# error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in java-mongodb example

Tags: java, mongodb

I have been trying to execute my first mongodb example in java. Its showing me the error. I have installed everything properly. Any help would be appreciated.it is throwing an exception Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.mongodb.ReadPreference.primary()Lcom/mongodb/ReadPreference;  at
>   com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.(MongoClientOptions.java:731)
>     at com.mongodb.MongoClient.(MongoClient.java:151)     at
>   com.mongodb.MongoClient.(MongoClient.java:141)  at
>   mongoDBExample.main(mongoDBExample.java:21)

This is my program code.

```
   public class mongoDBExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

    try {

    /**** Connect to MongoDB ****/

    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

    /**** Get database ****/
    // if database doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
    DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb");

    /**** Get collection / table from 'testdb' ****/
    // if collection doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
    DBCollection table = db.getCollection("user");

    /**** Insert ****/
    // create a document to store key and value


    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("name", "mkyong");
    document.put("age", "30");
    document.put("createdDate", new Date());
    table.insert(new DBObject[] {document});


    /**** Find and display ****/
    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    searchQuery.put("name", "mkyong");

    DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }

    /**** Update ****/
    // search document where name="mkyong" and update it with new values
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("name", "mkyong");

    BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
    newDocument.put("name", "mkyong-updated");

    BasicDBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject();
    updateObj.put("$set", newDocument);

    table.update(query, updateObj);

    /**** Find and display ****/
    BasicDBObject searchQuery2
        = new BasicDBObject().append("name", "mkyong-updated");

    DBCursor cursor2 = table.find(searchQuery2);

    while (cursor2.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor2.next());
    }

    /**** Done ****/
    System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MongoException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What version of mongo jar you are using? Which is your line 21?

Comment: @user3632894 mongo-java-driver-3.2.0

Comment: MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017); this is the 21st line.

Comment: I have tried running your code. It works fine. Make sure you have these import statements 
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;

Also you are using deprecated methods.

Comment: This is almost always a difference in versions between the build and deployment environments. Make sure you have the same jar versions in both places.

Comment: i tried reinstalling the mongodb server and tried running it once again.It worked fine for me as well.I dont what was the issue.Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue with

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
```

Try with format

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"));
```

Answer (score 0):

*In your Code the below line is throwing exception as it is depricated*

---

`DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb");`

---

Replace it with the below line and it should do the job

---

`MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);`

```
DB db = new DB(mongoClient, "testdb");
```

This should work;

Answer (score 0):

The right method

```
String client_url = "mongodb://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + "localhost" + ":" + port;

        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(client_url));
        
        
        MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongo.getDatabase(databaseName);
        
        //Creating a collection object
          MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection(collectionName);
        
        //Retrieving the documents
```

//            MongoIterable iterDoc = collection.find();;

Answer (score -1):

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new 
MongoClientURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"));
```

is the right solution to this problem

Comment: Please add a little more context to your answer.